# weapons in the State of Alaska

Tags: alaska

I own a house in Alaska, I live where for about 6 months, I do not have a green card, I go to the United States and I always remain legally, under the terms of my B2 visa, can I get weapons in the State of Alaska?

Comment: This is not really a travel question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: why is not a question about travel ? i go to US in holidays...it´s because i own a house in US ?

Comment: If by "a weapon" you mean "a firearm", then see [this information from the ATF](https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/may-nonimmigrant-alien-who-has-been-admitted-united-states-under-nonimmigrant-visa). Essentially you need to have an appropriate hunting permit or it is a federal crime. On top of that you would need to satisfy local state law. You may want to ask the question at http://law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Mario I'm pretty sure if you rephrase your question and elaborate a bit this should could be re-opened

Comment: You are allowed to bring Canadian firearms across the border with the appropriate paperwork for both sides, but if you intend to acquire it personally on the US side or leave it in the house it's not really a travel question. Even bringing 22LR ammo purchased in the US across the border as a Canadian runs up against tough munitions export laws.